# Sorting MySQL data using links from HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to allow a user to order a list by clicking a link and running php to sort it but I can't get it to work and I don't know why. The filters work fine, though since I am very new to PHP they probably aren't the most effective way to make them. I am trying to get the user click from the anchor tags at the end of the first html portion then sort the $student_query with the proper sort

```
<head>
<title>Student Data</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="registered.php" method="POST">
<h2>Filters:</h2>
Year of Graduation: <input type="text" id="yearFilter" name="yearFilter"/><br/>

Major:
<select name="majorFilter">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Creative Media and Entertainment">Creative Media and Entertainment</option>
    <option value="Interactive Media">Interactive Media</option>
    <option value="Recording Industry Studies">Recording Industry Studies</option>
    <option value="Sports Media">Sports Media</option>
</select><br />

Post-Grad Activity:
<select name="postGradFilter">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Employed">Employed</option>
    <option value="Graduate/Professional School or Advanced Coursework"> Graduate/Professional School or Advanced Coursework</option>
    <option value="Gap Year">Gap Year</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br />

<input type="submit" name="submitFilters" value="Filter" id="submitFilters" />


    </form>

</body>
//<a href="registered.php?sorting='.$sort.'&field=lastName">Sort By Name</a>
//<a href="registered.php?sorting='.$sort.'&field=gradDate">Sort By Graduation Year</a>
//<a href="registered.php?sorting='.$sort.'&field=major">Sort By Major</a>

<?php
include('includes/db_connect.php');

$sort = 'ASC';
$field = 'major.major';
$filter_gradYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['yearFilter']);
$filter_major = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['majorFilter']); 
$filter_postGrad = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['postGradFilter']);
$query_student;
if(isset($conn, $_POST['submitFilters'])){
    $query_student = "  SELECT *
                        FROM student
                        JOIN major
                        ON student.studentID=major.studentID
                        ";
    if(!empty($filter_gradYear) && empty($filter_major)){
        $query_student = "  SELECT *
                            FROM student
                            JOIN major
                            ON student.studentID=major.studentID AND gradDate = '$filter_gradYear'";
    }
    else if(!empty($filter_gradYear) && !empty($filter_major)){
        $query_student = "  SELECT *
                            FROM student
                            JOIN major
                            ON student.studentID=major.studentID AND (gradDate = '$filter_gradYear' AND major = '$filter_major')";
    }
    else if(empty($filter_gradYear) && !empty($filter_major)){
        $query_student = "  SELECT *
                            FROM student
                            JOIN major
                            ON student.studentID=major.studentID AND major = '$filter_major'";
    }
    if(!empty($filter_postGrad)){
        if($filter_postGrad == "Employed"){
        $query_student .= " JOIN jobSearch
                            ON major.studentID=jobSearch.studentID
                            JOIN job
                            WHERE jobSearch.studentID=job.studentID AND jobSearch.activity = '$filter_postGrad'";
        }
        else if($filter_postGrad == "Graduate/Professional School or Advanced Coursework"){
            $query_student .= " JOIN education
                                WHERE major.studentID=education.studentID";
        }
        else if($filter_postGrad == "Gap Year" || $filter_postGrad == "Other"){
            $query_student .= " JOIN jobSearch
                                WHERE major.studentID=jobSearch.studentID AND jobSearch.activity = '$filter_postGrad'";
        }
        else if($filter_postGrad == ""){

        }
    }

}

if(isset($_GET['sorting']))
{
  if($_GET['sorting']=='ASC')
  {
  $sort='DESC';
  }
  else { $sort='ASC'; }
}
if($_GET['field']=='lastName')
{ 
    $field = "student.lastName"; 
    $query_student .= "ORDER BY $field $sort";
}
else if($_GET['field']=='gradDate')
{
   $field = "major.gradDate";
   $query_student .= "ORDER BY $field $sort";
}
else if($_GET['field']=='major')
{ 
   $field="major.major";
   $query_student .= "ORDER BY $field $sort";
}
echo $query_student;
$result_student=mysqli_query($conn, $query_student) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th> 
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Graduate Year
        </th>
        <th>
            Major(s)
        </th>
        <th>Activity After Graduation</th>
        <?php
        if($filter_postGrad == "Employed") {
            echo '<th>Job Title</th>';
            echo '<th>Employer Name</th>';
            echo '<th>Earnings</th>';
            echo '<th>Is it their interest?</th>';
            echo '<th>Where was employment found?</th>';
            echo '<th>When did they start to search?</th>';
        }
        else if($filter_postGrad == "Graduate/Professional School or Advanced Coursework"){
            echo '<th>Location</th>';
            echo '<th>Institution</th>';
        }
        ?>
    </tr>

<?php

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_student)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['firstName']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['lastName']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gradDate']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['major']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['activity']?></td>
        <?php
        if($filter_postGrad == "Employed") {
            echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['employer'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['salary'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['interest'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['service'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['startSearch'] . '</td>';
         }  
         else if($filter_postGrad == "Graduate/Professional School or Advanced Coursework"){
             echo '<td>' . $row['location'] . '</td>';
             echo '<td>' . $row['schoolName'] . '</td>';
         }?>

    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<?php
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Could you output the SQL statement? I see you have one: `echo $query_student;` What is the SQL statement?

Comment: @ryanicle ORDER BY student.lastName ASC You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY student.lastName ASC' at line 1

Comment: Could you please provide full SQL statement, not just part of ORDER BY? It's easier to see in this way.

Comment: For some reason that is all it returns. It's not getting the "SELECT * FROM student..." part of the query in the sorting

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your php part.Please review & print $query_student.

```
<?php
include('includes/db_connect.php');

$sort = 'ASC';
$field = 'major.major';
$filter_gradYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['yearFilter']);
$filter_major = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['majorFilter']); 
$filter_postGrad = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['postGradFilter']);
$query_student ="";

$joinCond ="";
if(isset($conn, $_POST['submitFilters'])){
    $query_student = "  SELECT *
                        FROM student
                        JOIN major
                        ON student.studentID=major.studentID
                        ";

    if(!empty($filter_gradYear) && empty($filter_major)){
        $joinCond = " AND gradDate = '$filter_gradYear'";
    }
    else if(!empty($filter_gradYear) && !empty($filter_major)){
        $joinCond = " AND (gradDate = '$filter_gradYear' AND major = '$filter_major')";
    }
    else if(empty($filter_gradYear) && !empty($filter_major)){
        $joinCond = " AND major = '$filter_major'";
    }

$query_student = $query_student . $joinCond;
    if(!empty($filter_postGrad)){
        if($filter_postGrad == "Employed"){
        $query_student .= " JOIN jobSearch
                            ON major.studentID=jobSearch.studentID
                            JOIN job
                            WHERE jobSearch.studentID=job.studentID AND jobSearch.activity = '$filter_postGrad'";
        }
        else if($filter_postGrad == "Graduate/Professional School or Advanced Coursework"){
            $query_student .= " JOIN education
                                WHERE major.studentID=education.studentID";
        }
        else if($filter_postGrad == "Gap Year" || $filter_postGrad == "Other"){
            $query_student .= " JOIN jobSearch
                                WHERE major.studentID=jobSearch.studentID AND jobSearch.activity = '$filter_postGrad'";
        }
        else if($filter_postGrad == ""){

        }
    }

}

if(isset($_GET['sorting']))
{
  if($_GET['sorting']=='ASC')
  {
  $sort='DESC';
  }
  else { $sort='ASC'; }
}

if($_GET['field']=='lastName')
{ 
    $field = "student.lastName";     
}
else if($_GET['field']=='gradDate')
{
   $field = "major.gradDate";

}
else if($_GET['field']=='major')
{ 
   $field="major.major";   
}
if(!empty($field)
{
    $query_student .= " ORDER BY $field $sort";
}


echo $query_student;
$result_student=mysqli_query($conn, $query_student) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

?>
```

Comment: For some reason the $query_student only prints "ORDER BY student.lastName ASC". Why isn't it getting the rest of the query?

Comment: Please check my updated answer & print the $query_student

Answer (score 0):

In a previous answer I mentioned that you were missing a space before the `ORDER BY`. I still believe this is true (when filters are present), but I think there are a few other issues.

When you first go to the page (for example: `/registered.php?sort=DESC&field=major`) you are missing the first part of the `SELECT` because `$query_student` is never initialized to anything if `$_POST['submitFilters']` is not set.

Original code:

```
// When you first go to the page this will evaluate to 
// false and $query_student will never be initialized
if(isset($conn, $_POST['submitFilters'])){
    $query_student = "  SELECT *
                        FROM student
                        JOIN major
                        ON student.studentID=major.studentID
                     ";
```

This results in the echo only printing the `ORDER BY`. So, the first step is to move the default query above the `isset` check:

```
$query_student = "  SELECT *
                    FROM student
                    JOIN major
                    ON student.studentID=major.studentID
                 ";
if(isset($conn, $_POST['submitFilters'])){
```

There is another issue though. As soon as you submit the form you are going to lose the sort and field parameters because those are get parameters and you are submitting to "registered.php". You can fix this simply by removing the action tag from your form:

```
<form method="POST">
```

Now this will submit to the same page with the query string.